# How do I separate the files for 'widgets' in codeigniter?

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter, view, widget

I have a basic cms that loads content into pages that have mustache tags to indicate where in the html code those contents will appear.

The contents are specified in a widget model which indicate which type of content is to be displayed, so for example, freetext with id. or another model and id. each one of those models will be displayed differently based on the model they are based on.

I can imagine this becoming and bit unwieldy, is there a way to have a separate folder to put those widgets in so that it doesn't clutter my main code.

Something like apotomo does on rails would be good, but for codeigniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a *folder* inside application/views called *widgets*. Put your widgets inside that folder and create a separate file for each widget (d0h).

Next, you have 2 options (at least that i know of):

a.) Load the widgets into variables inside the controller, then pass them to the main/general view

```
$data['widget_twitter_feed'] = $this->load->view('widgets/twitter', '', false);
$data['widget_something'] = $this->load->view('widgets/something', '', false);

$this->load->view('my_main_view', $data);
```

b.) Load the widgets inside the main/general view itself

```
<html>
...
   <div id="sidebar">
      <?php $this->load->view('widgets/twitter'); ?>
   </div>
   ...
   <div id="footer">
      <?php $this->load->view('widgets/something'); ?>
   </div>
...
</html>
```

Comment: i agree with the (d0h). i was going to put the views in a widget folder but thought and extra step would be to put models and controllers elsewhere too. but that's a bit of overkill atm.

Answer (score 2):

A widget model? That is not so nice. Have you tried looking at [PyroCMS](http://pyrocms.com/)?

https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/blob/master/system/pyrocms/modules/widgets/libraries/Widgets.php

From the sound of it you may be more interested in our [Plugins](https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/blob/master/system/pyrocms/libraries/Plugins.php) library (sounds like the same thing with a different name). It is set up with a [MY_Parser](https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/blob/master/system/pyrocms/libraries/MY_Parser.php) and runs on top of Dan Horrigan's [Simpletags](http://hg.dhorrigan.com/simpletags) implementation.

Either way this has all be done plenty. If you want some more specific tailored advice you might have to demo some of your code.

Comment: the widget model is so that the end user doesn't need access to the template files, that template will show a general layout and the preview will render the final outcome. the end user will have the ability to switch the type of data they want displayed. 

the placeholders are just mustache labels and have no parameters, and the widget model just says put widget for model, id in placeholder {{foo}}

Comment: So you have a basic tag that calls up the widget model with a method that matches that name? That is easy enough. This does not need